# Microsoft headers have no comments on declarations so where is the documentation?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, include, documentation

Typically (as far as I know), in Visual Stdio I often right-click on a function "go to definition" or "go to declaration" with open source libraries. This leads me to the header files where I usually find a lot of documentation about the specific functions. If I try this with functions from Microsoft-headers, I get just some strange code, but no documentation about that function.

For example if I choose "go to declaration" with `printf`, I get this:

```
_Check_return_opt_
    _CRT_STDIO_INLINE int __CRTDECL printf(
        _In_z_ _Printf_format_string_ char const* const _Format,
        ...)
```

Do I miss something here? Does there exist another way? Where do you to look up these things?

Comment: You can look them up in the Microsoft [2017 Alphabetical Function Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crt-alphabetical-function-reference?view=vs-2017).

Comment: The lack of comments also means that Microsoft's Intellisense is borderline useless.  You type "object.Method(" or "printf(" and it just pops-up with the method signature.  Strangely, Microsoft has the complete opposite mentality with their other languages. C#, VB, and Powershell all provide extensive documentation built-in.  My current approach is to ask chatGPT: it provides phenomenal documentation and seems to have aggregated multiple sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Microsoft code is not self-documenting in this way. They're not intended to be read by mere mortals. That's just a choice that was made by the developers. Different projects take different approaches to documentation. Some sprinkle comments liberally, others write out-of-band documentation (such as [on Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/printf-printf-l-wprintf-wprintf-l?view=vs-2019)), and some don't bother providing any at all!

For Windows stuff I will typically Google e.g. `printf visual studio`.